# Compare two sets with large amount of data to find the same values

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, graph, set

Ok, the problem looks like this. I have a set of `n` database rows with empty column `position`. I need to use address data (different combinations etc. - it doesn't matter) from that set (from 3 separated columns) to compare them with the another set of `m` elements (also from database, which contain address data and needed **location**).

Because these sets are very large (about milion records, and the operation is executed quite often), I need some pretty fast algorithm to compare these two sets and find the data I need.

I tried to find something, but I have no idea if it's any well-known mathematical problem (in graph theory maybe?).

**[edit]**

The structures are too large to describe them here. But I will make an example for that.

**Set 1.**

```
|[ID] | [CITY] | [STREET] | [POSTCODE] | [LOCATION] |
|-----|--------|----------|------------|------------|
| 1   | City1  | Street1  | 00000      | NULL       |
| 2   | City2  | Street2  | 11111      | NULL       |
| 3   | City3  | Street3  | 22222      | NULL       |
```

**Set 2.**

```
|[ID] | [SOME_KIND_OF_ADDRESS]              | [LOCATION] |
|-----|-------------------------------------|------------|
| 1   | Street 1 in City 1, 00000 blah blah | SOME_XY1   |
| 2   | Street 2 in City 1, 00001 blah blah | SOME_XY2   |
| 3   | Street 2 in City 2, 11111 blah blah | SOME_XY3   |
| 4   | Street 1 in City 4, 33333 blah blah | SOME_XY4   |
```

Now for each element in `Set 1`, I want to try to find something in `Set 2`. In this case only `City2, Street2` and `City1, Street1` will be matched. So the result will look like:

```
|[ID] | [CITY] | [STREET] | [POSTCODE] | [LOCATION] |
|-----|--------|----------|------------|------------|
| 1   | City1  | Street1  | 00000      | SOME_XY1   |
| 2   | City2  | Street2  | 11111      | SOME_XY3   |
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your structure, data and expected result

Comment: 1) why not SOME_XY1 in result?

2) if postcode is always common, then you can compare them in groups. this would be N^2 times faster (when you have N different postcodes)

Comment: 1. My bad xD sorry. 2. In the future `postcode` can be joined with `some_kind_of_address`, so there will be problematic again. I see now, my example is a little confusing. I will correct it

Comment: Ok, I made an edit, now everything should be more clear:)

Comment: To compare Address, you'll have to parse Address in Set 2

Comment: Yes, but the problem is I have large amount of data and I don't want to compare them one-to-one. I'm looking for more clever way to do this (if it exists)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do this is to parse the addresses in set 2 and then create indexes on each of the fields.  Then your comparisons will be really fast.

Absent that, what are your options?  Well, you basically have to scan all of the addresses in set 2 for the comparisons.  Some SQL engines optimize comparisons at the beginning of the string (using indexes), so one comparison could use an index.  If you have a function to extract the street/city/postcode, then some databases can support "functional" indexes where the elements are t the results of function calls.

Another option is full text search.  This would let you search for the components, using a structure called an inverted index.

However, my advice is to fix the addresses and extract the pieces that you want for comparison.  Address rectification/standardization, although neither cheap nor fast, usually pays for itself in the medium term by greatly simplifying requests such as this.

Comment: Yes, this will be the best idea. Then I can cache index data to use them in the future, because `Set 2` changes rarely. Thx

Answer (score 0):

i'd use the following algorithm:

1. Sort tables A,B
2. Create 2 pointers (ptrA, ptrB) at the beginning of the tables
3. While (ptrA has not ended and ptrB has not ended)

{

```
if (ptrA->value=ptrB->value) update column position
if (ptrA->value>ptrB->value) move prtB forward
else move ptrA forward
```

}

Comment: Sorting the data is an idea, but it need to be modified. Please, look at my example. The data from `Set 2` can be represented in a strange form (I mean address), it depends on where that data come from.